# Taylor series on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, taylor-series

I need some help for the following problem.

Let $M$ a riemannian manifold and $f$ a smooth differential function, then consider the following integral $$\int_M \Gamma(x,y)(f(y)-f(x))dV_y$$

where $dV_y$ is the measure on the manifold and $\Gamma$ is a positive function. Now, my question is how can do a taylor expansion of the integral, i.e., for example in the case of $M=\mathbb R$, we have with $y=x-\epsilon z$, $$\int_\mathbb{R}\Gamma(x,x-\epsilon z)(f(x-\epsilon z)-f(x))dy=\int_\mathbb{R}\Gamma(x,x-\epsilon z)(-\epsilon z f'(x)+(\epsilon z)^2f''(x)+...)(-\epsilon dz)$$

But now if I'm on a Riemannian manifold, how can I do something like that? I don't know any taylor series like that. Anyway, for the case of the manifold I tried to occupy the exponential map and the polar coordinates.

Thanks any idea will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Likely you have a relation between Г and the Riemannin metric --- if so tell us what is it. Otherwise, why not to embed the manifold in the Euclidean space and do the analysis there?

Answer (score 5):

If you fix $x\in M$, you can set up a [Riemann normal coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) chart $(z^i)$ centered at $x$. Then you can just do the usual Taylor series expansion in $z$. Semi-globally, in a normal convex neighborhood of the diagonal $\Delta \subset \mathcal{U} \subset M\times M$, you can define the geodesic distance function $r(x,y)$ between $x,y \in \mathcal{U}$. The function $\sigma(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} r(x,y)^2$ is sometimes called *(Synge's) world function*. It's gradient in the $y$ variable $\sigma^j(x,y) = g^{jk}(y) \nabla_k \sigma(x,y)$ is a good substitute for the normal coordinate difference $z^j = y^j - x^j$ and is defined on the whole neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of the diagonal $\Delta$. A Taylor expansion of the form
$$
  f(y) = f(x) + f_i(x) \sigma^i(x,y) + \frac{1}{2} f_{ij}(x) \sigma^i(x,y) \sigma^j(x,y) + \cdots
$$
is sometimes called the *covariant Taylor series* for $f$. Similar expansions can be done also for tensor fields, not just scalars.

Covariant Taylor series have been extensively used for some specific applications in theoretical and mathematical physics (see for instance the [PhD thesis of Avramidi](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9510140) from 1986).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but why you say a good substitute for the difference of coordinates? And second, what is $\nabla_k \sigma(x,y)$ I understand this is a covariant derivative, so ¿ 'k' is the coordinate index?. Thanks!

Comment: @Andresito Yes, $g^{jk}\nabla_k$ in what I wrote is the covariant derivative wrt to $y$ with tensor index raised by the metric $g^{jk}(y)$ at $y$. It is easy to see that $\sigma^j(x,y) = O(x-y)$ in any coordinate system $(y^j)$, hence good enough for a Taylor expansion. Even better, $\sigma^j(x,y) = z^j$ when $(z^j)$ are normal coordinates centered at $x$ (compare their definitions!).